# Run application multiply times without stop previous

Tags: javascript

I have a clock application that I would be able to run multiply times, but everytime I start the application again, the previous one stops. I think i should use target ? och This. But i cant figure out where in the function I should use it.

The function for the clock.

```
function myFunction() {
    startClock();

    function startClock() {
        var digits = new Array("zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine");
        var h = new Date().getHours().toString();
        var m = new Date().getMinutes().toString();
        var s = new Date().getSeconds().toString();
        var t = ((h > 9 ? h : "0" + h) + (m > 9 ? m : "0" + m) + (s > 9 ? s : "0" + s));

        hours.appendChild(hour1).className = "clock-digit-" + digits[t.substring(0, 0 + 1)];
        hours.appendChild(hour2).className = "clock-digit-" + digits[t.substring(1, 1 + 1)];
        minutes.appendChild(minute1).className = "clock-digit-" + digits[t.substring(2, 2 + 1)];
        minutes.appendChild(minute2).className = "clock-digit-" + digits[t.substring(3, 3 + 1)];
        seconds.appendChild(sec1).className = "clock-digit-" + digits[t.substring(4, 4 + 1)];
        seconds.appendChild(sec2).className = "clock-digit-" + digits[t.substring(5, 5 + 1)];

        t = setTimeout(function () {
            startClock()
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

I have created a jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dymond/nufwb/

But as you notice  when you press test twice the prev. clock stops...

Comment: You're using global variables, so they can only refer to one set of elements. You need to collect everything into an object, and pass it as a parameter to your function.

Comment: @Barmar Hey, thanks. But i really can get how you mean. I f i move the vars into an object and call the parameter from the function, ill get the same problem. probably doing something wrong.

Comment: You won't have the same problem if you do everything with local variables. Each run of the function will create new variables, and they won't conflict with each other.

Comment: @Barmar well, that's the problem where i don't get it :)
because all my variables are inside the function myFunction. doesn't that make them local ?

Comment: I'm talking about the variables `hours`, `hour1`, `minutes`, etc. These global variables are set by `clock()` and used by `myFunction()`. Each time you click the button it calls `clock()`, which overwrites these variables.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry but i cant get i work, I understand how you mean with the overwrite. And i created the global variable inside a object called wrap. and run the wrap function from  clock() but still. same problem.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time to post an answer with the full rewrite. If you post your new version, maybe someone will be able to spot the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining variables outside of `myFunction()`.

```
var t1 = setTimeout(function(){startClock()},1000);
var t2 = setTimeout(function(){startClock()},2000);
```

What you are doing now is overwriting the previous clock every time you run `myFunction()`.